# BeautifulSoup findAll tags with mutliple classes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I'm trying to loop through a list of search results on a website. The search results are nested under div tags with two different classes, "result-item standard" and "result-item standard  basic ad". I want the search results to be found in order of appearance. How do I include multiple classes within my findAll? Or is there another way to do this?

My current code is below:

```
for div in soup.findAll("div", {"class": ["result-item standard", "result-item standard  basic ad"]}):
    #item_title = " ".join(div.h2.a.text.split())
    item = div.h2.a.text.split()
    item_year = item[0]
    item_make = item[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a bit slower, but uses the `class_` selector:

```
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="result-item standard") + soup.find_all("div", class_="result-item standard  basic ad")     
for div in divs:
    item = div.h2.a.text.split()
    item_year = item[0]
    item_make = item[1]
```

The syntax you are using is BS3, the syntax in this answer is BS4.

Answer (score 3):

I would just make a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for div in soup.select("div.result-item.standard"):
    # ...
```

`div.result-item.standard` would match `div` elements having both `result-item` and `standard` classes.